# Get users registration time?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am working on a PHP application and it is centered around a MySQL database, I want to have the user's registration time automatically recorded.

- Which would be better? Using PHP's date function or does MySQL have a current timestamp option (I think it does).
- If MySQL is better (in terms of accuracy) then how would I implement it? What would the table structure be?
- If PHP is better (in terms of accuracy) then what would be the most straight forward way of doing that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [MySQL DateTime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-date) reference.

I would recommend using `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` in MySQL then you take timezones out of the equation and are pretty accurate.

```
mysql> SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UTC_TIMESTAMP() + 0;
    -> '2003-08-14 18:08:04', 20030814180804.000000
```

If you use it as a string you'll get back date format, if you use it as a numerical selector you'll get back a numerical value.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a look over and then get back.

Answer (score 1):

This Following MYSQL Code Will Do It:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (date_field) VALUE (now())
```

In terms of accuracy, MYSQL will be closest to the time of insert, but the difference between PHP and MYSQL is so minimal it will not make a difference.

Comment: I'm not sure thats's the simplest... I think I should use a default so I dont have to manually configure it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the MySQL function [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) when inserting the record.

Both PHP and MySQL will use the time from the system clock so the results should be the same regardless of which you use.  Timestamps are also stored in UTC so they can easily be switched to the user's timezone.

IMO, it makes no difference which you use (PHP or MySQL time), but I would personally store the registration time in an `INT` column as a timestamp.

The insert may look like:

```
INSERT INTO `user`
(id, username, registrationTime)
VALUES
(NULL, 'rgbc', UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer these in order.

- I always recommend using MySQL's time function (which is NOW()) because it makes for cleaner and more-efficient code. Although the performance difference is slight, it is simpler to use NOW() in your INSERT query than using PHP's date() function to set a variable and then call it later in your query.
- If it's accuracy you seek, use the InnoDB engine for your database. An example structure would be: id (int auto_increment), name (tinytext), password (tinytext), salt (tinytext), registerd_date (DATETIME). The password and salt columns are for using a secure, hashed password (with something like SHA512).
- PHP is probably the easiest, in my opinion. The most straightforward way is doing a regular registration form, and then using NOW() to record the date and time for when the registration occurred.

Good luck,

David

Comment: Should I set the default for reg_time to NOW() ?

Comment: If you wanted to use a default value, then TIMESTAMP is the type of column you would have to use, because DATETIME does not allow it. But, yes, that is possible